# Fuzzy regex Elasticsearch

Tags: python, regex, elasticsearch, fuzzy-search

I am trying to find matches between words and there reduced form using Elasticsearch.

Let say I have the input word `shmp` (indexed as `shampoo` in ES), I generate the following regex `s.*?h.*?m.*?p.*?` and execute the following query DSL:

```
{
  "query": {
    "regexp": { "name": "s.*?h.*?m.*?p.*?" }
  }
}
```

Is there a way to also do a fuzzy search in the same time (of max_expansions 1 for example) so that `s.*h.*?n.*?p.*?` would match ?

However I'm not sure that is the best way to go, maybe there are some work around that I did not think of.

Comment: What about `s.*?h.*?[mn].*?p.*?`?

Comment: actually the letter that could diverge is unknown. Too easy otherwise ;)

Comment: So use in that case you can use a character range `s.*?h.*?[a-z].*?p.*?` or other regex for example you can also use `\w` to match all word characters.

Comment: the `m` becoming an `n` was an example. I mean that the `s` or the `h` could be the wrong letter like `fhmp` or `sump`. (Even if i am aware that a lot of other words could match)

Answer (score 1):

This solution is different than @ezig's answer. A different take on it :p

```
^(.*?([^s](?=.*?h.*?m.*?p)|s).*?([^h](?=.*?m.*?p)|h).*?([^m](?=.*?p)|m).*?.)
```

[Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/oA1zY3/1)

The way this regular expression basically works is that each letter gets a section. For this explanation we'll use `s` since it's first.

S: `([^s](?=.*?h.*?m.*?p)|s)`

This says *"you're allowed to not match an `s` here assuming that the rest of the string will properly match otherwise we need to match an `s` here"*

To see why this regular expression will grow more slowly than @ezig's answer is that we know that the first character will follow the rules of your fuzzy match and we dont have to be too clever with the additional characters.

H: `([^h](?=.*?m.*?p)|h)`

The section is shorted because we know that if `s` didn't match we wouldn't match the string at all but since we're checking `h` here and it might be different we know it had to match `s` previously. This says *"If the rest of the string matches properly then we can match something other than `h`"*.

Answer (score 0):

`(..*?h.*?m.*?p.*?|s.*?..*?m.*?p.*?|s.*?h.*?..*?p.*?|s.*?h.*?m.*?..*?)`

https://regex101.com/r/qV9cW6/1

It's kind of messy to generate by hand because it will involve an OR statement with the number of terms equal to the number of letters in the input. But if you used a loop it wouldn't be too bad to generate it for an arbitrary input. The way it works is that it allows cases where any one of the 4 characters `shmp` is a different character, but no more than one.

Comment: Is regex the only way for the fuzzy search part ? (to only look using regex and not built-in ES features). Let say I want a max_expansions of 4 on a 8 letter words, the regex will be pretty large.

Comment: There might be a better way to do it using ES features – I'm not familiar with Elasticsearch (only regex) so I'm not sure.